# Javascript file uploads

Tags: javascript

Any alternate thing in JavaScript to make a file upload control ?

---

actually the problem was, i am creating file upload control dynamically using htmlwriter, and when i use `request.form[fileuplodctrl].tostring()` , i am getting only the file name not path...

can any one suggest me any other ways to get full file path :)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 20):

Here are a few alternatives:

- [YUI Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/)
- [jqUploader](http://www.pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/) (jQuery plugin)
- [jQuery Multiple File Uploader](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) (jQuery plugin)
- [Dojo FileUploader](https://user.sitepen.com/~mwilcox/dojotoolkit/demos/uploader/demo.html)
- [jUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/) (Applet)

Comment: +1 for SWFUpload - it is a great utility

Comment: jQuery Multiple File Uploader - not functional anymore

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no possibility to upload a file with pure JavaScript. You alway need some like a swf movie or a java applet (probably it will also work with a silverlight app).
If you do not like to write your own, use one the existing ones from the last answer ([Javascript file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408735/javascript-file-uploads#408736)).

Comment: Speaking from the distant future, the year 2012, it is now possible with pure Javascript using HTML5 (and a hidden iframe for legacy browsers): https://github.com/bencolon/file-uploader

Comment: @Blaise - GREAT SCOTT!!

Comment: It's fun how things change within a few years...