# How to automatically upload a file once it has been "Browsed" without submitting the form

Tags: file, forms, upload

I have a website were users can create a profile and upload an image for their avatar.  The way I have it set up now is a simple HTML form one with an upload box where you Browse to pick a file, and then press "upload" to submit the form.

**What technology/language would be the best to have the image automatically upload and display on the page once the file is selected WITHOUT submitting the form.**

A live example of what I would like is how Gmail uploads their attachments automatically once you pick the file from the file browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/), which is JavaScript/Flash based.

Check the [demos](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408735/javascript-file-uploads/408736#408736) question for more alternatives.