# How do I use AJAX to upload files to ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload files using AJAX to ASP.NET. I have this Javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   xhr.open('post', '/File/Upload', true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("_file", files[i]);
   xhr.send(files[i]);
}
```

`files` is an `Array()`

Then I try to access the post file in C# code, but the value is always `null`. How can I resolve this issue?

```cs
// Method 1, Result: file = null
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["_file"];

// Method 2, Result: postedFile.Count = 0
HttpFileCollectionBase postedFile = Request.Files;
```

Comment: are you getting any exceptions

Comment: Nothing, no error, no exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the following form containing the file input field:

```
<form action="/home/index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return handleSubmit(this);">
    <input type="file" id="_file" name="_file" multiple="multiple" />
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

you could try the following function:

```
function handleSubmit(form) {
    if (!FormData) {
        alert('Sorry, your browser doesn\'t support the File API => falling back to normal form submit');
        return true;
    }

    var fd = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById('_file');
    for (var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++) {
        fd.append('_file', file.files[i]);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(fd);

    return false;
}
```

Now on the server you should be able to retrieve the file using `Request.Files`.

Comment: I've seen that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211145/upload-file-with-ajax-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Yeap, this is using the HTML5 File API.

Comment: What do you mean with File API? You mean the Browse button?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. You are already using the File API. I have updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: I don't know if it change something, but I'm not using HTML for my form. I'm using a sencha form with a filefield to open the browse window and get the files. Here is the filefield doc, see the Live Preview: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File

Comment: That's working, but How can I send multiple parameters? I tried : `xhr.send("files = " + formData + "&folderId = " + otherParameter);`, but with that I don't get any of the parametters...

Comment: You just add them to the `FormData` instance: `fd.append('folderId', otherParameter);`. As far as the send call is concerned it should stay unchanged, as shown in my answer: `xhr.send(fd);`.

Comment: How do I know when a file from the `file` array is uploaded?

Comment: A file is uploaded when the form is submitted, that's why you subscribed to the `onsubmit` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery

you have 2 functions
Ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Load(shortcut, calls ajax) : http://api.jquery.com/load/
Examples : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp

**Edited** : 2012-10-04 16:31 
**Reason** : Got the following Comment : 
*Hm unless I don't understand, I don't want to load informations of the server, I want to get the informations I have in my JS code on my server. I already have the informations to send in the files Array(). – Elfayer*

What you do is you make a AJAX call to the server like to an webservice.
Here is an example

```
var value = 1;
var handlerUrl = [YOUR WEBSERVICE URL];

//Do the Ajax Call
jQuery.ajax({
  url: handlerUrl,
  data: { "params[]": [value] },
  type: 'POST',
  success: function (data)
  {
     alert("succes");
  },
  error: function (jxhr, msg, err)
  {
     alert("error");
  }
});
```

in the data parameter you give your data. 
I send it here in the form of an array but you can send it also like 1 parameter.
How do you access it in well in my case a generic handler.

```
//Split the parameters and set in Array of Strings
var param = context.Request.Form[0].Split(',');
var value = param[0];
```

Like I said I give it in the form of an array so I only have one parameter 
and then I split it. But if you would give it like single properties then you 
could get it like :

```
context.Request.Form[0]
context.Request.Form[1]
context.Request.Form[2]
context.Request.Form[3]
context.Request.Form[4]
```

Comment: Hm unless I don't understand, I don't want to load informations of the server, I want to get the informations I have in my JS code on my server. I already have the informations to send in the `files` Array().

Comment: Interesting ! But how can I send an object? Because files is an Array() of objects, and each object contain the informations of a file. If I do : `data: { "params[]": [files[i]] },` I get : `value = [Object File]`. Then, I already have an upload method that work with a single file upload (I'm doing a multiple file Upload). And this method currently work if I can get an `HttpPostedFile` or maybe (certainly) `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Comment: Hm... I never tried that tbh. But did a bit google search and it seems that's not possible. You have to use a file upload control. Look here for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408735/javascript-file-uploads

Comment: A little bit more googling and found a possible solution : http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/ (It is a PHP tutorial though)