# I need to get the value of an asp.net fileupload into Ajax parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to get the value of an asp.net fileupload into Ajax parameter and i'm trying to do like this:

```
$('#<%=fileUpload.ClientID%>').val() 

//and in the WebMethod  
[WebMethod]
public static List<AjaxCategory> AddCategory(FileUpload categoryImage)
```

I don't know if it is possible or not, but like this is not working

Comment: `Eliza` look at this previous stackoverflow posting and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726172/how-do-i-use-ajax-to-upload-files-to-asp-net

Comment: no becuase I'm using ASP FileUpload

Comment: Eliza can you show the aspx code for the page also have you tried getting at the value from the document level using the `document.getElementById("Name of your TextBox");` you could also use JavaScript. I am not sure what you are trying to do with that static method because you haven't provided enough information either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async file upload requires some additional setup.  Look to using a utility like:

- AJAX control toolkit [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx)
- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
- HTML 5 [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access) (also [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/))
- Others