# How To Hide The Browser Progress Bar While Specific Iframe Loads or any kind of process happen inside it

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a page inside it a iframe inside this iframe i do my upload file staff all what i want to do here is how to hide the progress bar or make it not working when a post back happens inside this iframe in javascript

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide the iframe status, but you can work around it to achieve the same result:

You can upload files via [XHR2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/). This isn't supported by many browsers yet due to the draft being quiet new.

For IE users you can create an `htmlfile`([More info Here](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/18/ie-activexhtmlfile-transport-part-ii/)) that mimics an iframe but isn't part of the DOM using activeX: `new ActiveXObject("htmlfile");`

For those that do not support the previous you can use alternatives such as a flash plugin. For more info about these alternatives check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408735/javascript-file-uploads).

As a quick note, both jqUploader's and jquery-multifile-uploader's fall back is the importing of a flash object.

Comment: +1 sorta useful to me but jquery did it in the file upload plug in so there must be a way to do it :) thanks any way

Comment: which plugin? the two I mentioned above attempt to use xhr2 then fall back to htmlfile if IE, then fall back to importing a flash if no other possibility

Comment: What you just linked doesn't actually upload the files. it allows the user to select multiple files to upload